# Z-index and position sticky paradox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that z-index has problems with different positionings and in this snippet I need them to work together so that I could replicate the navigation on this website http://www.ericryananderson.com/
The problem is that when the overlay is activated the button needs to be z-indexed which the position sticky doesn't like and doesn't allow it causing the overlay to be unclosable. The position sticky is on the nav bar. Is there a workaround this?

```js
var bars = document.querySelector('.bars')
var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay')

var isMenuOpened = false;

bars.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (isMenuOpened === false) {
    bars.classList.remove('fa-bars');
    bars.classList.add('fa-times');
    overlay.style.display = 'block'
    isMenuOpened = true;

    bars.style.position  = 'fixed'
    bars.style.top = '40px';
    bars.style.right = '60px';


  }else{
    bars.classList.remove('fa-times');
    bars.classList.add('fa-bars');
    overlay.style.display = 'none'

    bars.style.position  = 'static'
    isMenuOpened = false;



  }


})
```

```css
body{
  height: 3000px;
}
.video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: red;
}
nav{
  display: flex;
  /* position: sticky; */
  top: 0px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 50px;
  background: green;
  height: 10px;
}

i{
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 10;

}
.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="video">

    </div>
    <div class="navigation">

      <nav>
        <h4>koreys site</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-bars bars"></i>

      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay">

    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I'm able to open and close the overlay in your dialog without issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with sticky elements and overlay/modal. Hope to hear a solution.